# How to test parent-child kafka based projects with junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, apache-kafka

Child module receives the request from parent's kafka producer. Child module has only kafak receive and send functionalities. Whereas parent gets request from rest api and then it produces to child's kafka listner.

I want to write integration test case for the above project structure. I want to test whole application i.e. receive the rest api call and then forward request to child module and send the response back.

Here is the project structure

[image]

This is the api controller where initial request lands:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController {

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemple;

@RequestMapping(value={"/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public PojoClass welcomeUser(@RequestBody String request) {

    // TODO Prepares request to JSON format and forward towards child module
    kafkaTemple.send("ChildTopic", request);

    return new PojoClass("Test","Test Message String");
  }
}
```

Child kafka receiver and producer

```
@Component
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaReceiver extends config {

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemple;

private static final String kafkaTopic = "ChildTopic";

@KafkaListener(topics = kafkaTopic)
public void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) {

    // TODO Some parsing and validation

    System.out.println("Received request: " + records);
    kafkaTemple.send("ParentTopic", records + " :Response-true");

  }
}
```

Here is the parent kafka receiver

```
@Component
@EnableKafka
public class ParentKafkaReceiver extends config {

private static final String kafkaTopic = "ParentTopic";

@KafkaListener(topics = kafkaTopic)
public void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) {

    System.out.println("Final result string: " + records);
  }
}
```

Where and how should I write test cases ? i.e. in parent module or child module

Comment: You should write the tests in src/test/java, not the modules themselves. Parent child doesn't really matter as long as you can import all the relevant classes

Comment: Yes true. Tests should be in src/test/java. But do I need to test main code from api controller or bypass it and start testing code from kafka listner through embedded kafka ?

Comment: Integration tests that rely on a broker should use embedded Kafka. Otherwise, and code that is testing transformations or filtering of data can be mocked using arraylists